# itext-asian.jar required to support chinese characters for itext v 5.0.5

Tags: itext

We are using itext v5.0.5 commercial license. We need itext-asian.jar to support the Chinese characters. I couldn't find the itext-asian.jar for itext v 5.0.5 online. We are not in the position to upgrade to latest version of itext as it involves lot of testing. Could you please give a path to download the itext-asian.jar for version 5.0.5?

Comment: Please contact support at iText Software using the proper channel and they'll help you out. As a customer, you should have access to the ticketing system at iText Software. I'm answering from my phone, so it's hard to check which version of the Asian jar is needed for 5.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the changelog, and I see that itext-asian.jar changed in [iText 5.2.0](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/520). From that moment on, you needed [extrajars-2.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/extrajars-2.2.zip/download).

iText 5.0.5 dates from [November 2, 2010](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/505). When I check the contents of [extrajars-2.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/extrajars-2.1.zip/download), I see that it contains an itext-asian.jar dating from May 21, 2011.

I then checked [extrajars-2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/extrajars-2.0.zip/download) and much to my surprise this also contained an itext-asian.jar dating from May 6, 2011.

I guess these extrajars zip files were updated simultaneously 5 years ago. I think both of the itext-asian.jar files will work with iText 5.0.5. Please start by testing the most recent one first.

Comment: itext-asian.jar from extrajars-2.2 doesn't work. itext-asian.jar that is part of extrajars-2.1 and extrajars-2.0 does work. I read that itext version needs to match with itext-asian.jar. We are using itext 5.0.5 but itext-asian.jar that is part of extrajars-2.1 or extrajars-2.0 is for itext 5.1. Will it be an issue in using itext-asian 5.1 with itext 5.0.5?

Comment: Hi, since the extrajars-2.0 and 2.1 were posted in the same month, I am pretty sure extrajars-2.0 was for iText 5.0 and extrajars-2.1 was for 5.1.

Comment: I looked at pom.xml and pom.properties within itext-asian.jar of extrajars-2.0 and it says version 5.1.0. itext-asian.jar of extrajars-2.0 and extrajars-2.1 looks the same on comparison.

Comment: am I good to use extrajars-2.0 with itext 5.0.5 even though pom.xml and pom.properties mention as version 5.1.0?

Comment: @Muni Yes, I'm pretty sure the POM was added after the fact.